Show that $A_n=\frac{n! (30n)!}{(6n)!(10n)!(15n)!} $ can't be written as a product of binomial coefficients of the form $\binom{a_in}{b_in} $.
Let $ n > 0 $ and
$$
A_n=\frac{n! (30n)!}{(6n)!(10n)!(15n)!} 
$$
(a)Show that the number $A_n$ can't be written as a product of binomial coefficients. (see edit, not just any binomial coefficient)
(b) Show that $A_n$ is integral for any $ n \geq 0 $
My try:
I have proven (b), but I am having trouble with (a):
(b) I used Legendre's formula
$$
\nu_p(n!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \right\rfloor.
$$
to compute the exponent of a prime $p $ in the decomposition of $A_n$ (denoted ord$_p(A_n)$ or $\nu_p(A_n)$):
$
\nu_p(A_n) = \nu_p(n!) + \nu_p((30n)!) - \nu_p((6n)!) - \nu_p((10n)!) - \nu_p((15n)!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{30n}{p^i} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{6n}{p^i} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{10n}{p^i} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{15n}{p^i} \right\rfloor \right).
$
Doing $ x= \frac{n}{p^i}$ we get
$\nu_p(A_n) =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[ \left( \left\lfloor 30x \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \right) - \left( \left\lfloor 6x \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor 10x \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor 15x \right\rfloor \right)] \geq 0,
$
$
f(x) := \left( \left\lfloor 30x \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \right) - \left( \left\lfloor 6x \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor 10x \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor 15x \right\rfloor \right) \geq 0,
$ can be written in terms of the fractional part $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$
$f(x) =  \{6x\} + \{10x\} + \{15x\} - \{30x\} - \{x\}$ which is 1-periodic and is proven to take only values 0 or 1, so  $f(x)\ge 0$  from this $\nu_p(A_n)\ge 0$ which shows that $A_n$ is integral
(a) A binomial coefficient is given by:
$$
\binom{a}{b} = \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}.
$$
A product of binomial coefficients of the required form is
$$
B_n:=\binom{a_1n}{b_1n} \binom{a_2n}{b_2n} \cdots \binom{a_rn}{b_rn}.
$$
Since
$
\nu_p\left( \binom{a}{b} \right) = \nu_p(a!) - \nu_p(b!) - \nu_p((a-b)!$
Then
$ \nu_p(B_n)=\nu_p\left( \prod_{i=1}^{r} \binom{a_in}{b_in} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \nu_p\left( \binom{a_in}{b_in} \right).
$
But I don't think this helps. Assuming that $A_n=B_n$  so that  $\nu_p(A_n)=\nu_p(B_n)$ takes me nowhere How should I do this?
These numbers are called Chebyschev numbers by the way
Edit:Clarification In  (a) we don't know that $A_n$ is an integer.  The question is about not being able to write $A_n$ as the product of binomial coefficients of the form $\binom{a_in}{b_in} $ for different integers $a_i , b_i $ independent of $n$. I have updated my try accordingly, to rule out what was suggested in the comments My question remains the same, though
Hint:  See why there is no way to cancel $n!$ in the numerator: then the number of factorials in the numerator is 2, in the denominator is 3, exactly by 1 more than in the numerator. Same balance for the binomial coefficients, which we do know are integers

I would have thought every integer can be written as a product of binomial coefficients if you allow more than two binomial coefficients.  For example $275={5 \choose 1}{5\choose 1}{11\choose 1}$.

@Henry I am not sure if the question means it can't be written as a product of exactly 2 binomial coeffs. So you say that for more than 2 it is not true?

The motivation is to see that not all integer ratios of factorials are reducible to binomials.

Strictly speaking, every positive integer $k$ can be written as the product of two binomial coefficients, for example with ${k \choose 1}{1\choose 1}$. So $A_n={A_n \choose 1}{1 \choose 1}$ if $A_n$ is an integer, even if the quotient $A_n= \dfrac{{31n \choose 6n}{25n \choose 10n}}{31n \choose n}$ might be more useful.

@Henry The image from the book that I pasted is all the motivation is given for this problem,plus proving that a binomial coefficient is integer using the analogous procedure as in the solution of (b), but then what is the sense of the question? Somehow these trivial cases should be not consider I think

$A_n$ is at OEIS A211417

@Henry I got clarification In  (a) we don't know that $A_n$ is an integer. see Edit.

Can you show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} ( (k-1)n, kn )$ contains a prime for any positive integer $k$?  If so, you should be able to show that such a product would contain $\binom{30n}{bn}$ for some $1 \leq b \leq 29$.  Divide both sides by this binomial coefficient and repeat.

@BrianMoehring I got another hint for this, see my post, but I am not sure how to use it.  Does it tell you anything? Regarding your proposal I haven't been able to prove that and I don't understand either how that Union relates to the product containing that binomial coefficient and what i need to repeat

Personally, I find your explanation for part (a) unclear.  What does the expression $~\displaystyle \binom{a_i ~n}{b_i ~n}~$ signify?  That is: [1] What does the expression $~a_i ~n~$ signify in relation to your specification for $~A_n ~?~$ [2] What does the expression $~b_i ~n~$ signify in relation to your specification for $~A_n ~?~$

In addition to my confusion, re my previous comment, I wonder if there is a typo in your specification for $~B_n.~$ Should it instead be $$
B_n:=\binom{a_1n}{b_1n} \binom{a_2n}{b_{\color{red}{2}}n} \cdots \binom{a_rn}{b_rn} ~?
$$

@user2661923 Not sure I follow you, that expression is a binomial coefficient, a_in choose b_in, as writen in the definition of $B_n$ ( te product of a certain number of these binomials is called B_n ). Why want to see that $A_n=B_n$ is not possible for any number of factors $r$ or values $a_i,b_i$  positive integers.  Is it clear?

I fixed the typo

This is based on the hint you gave: once we express $A_n$ as a product of $r$-many $\binom{a_i n}{b_i n}$'s, then after suitable cancellations of factorials, we have $r$ more factorials on the denominator than the numerator, and you have 1 more factorials on the denominator of $A_n$ than the numerator, which gives $r = 1$ and a contradiction.
Here's a way to make this more rigorous using Stirling's formula. I'm pretty sure that there's a better way, but anyway I think this proof is interesting. Stirling's formula says
$$
n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$
as $n \to \infty$, and by taking log,
$$
\log(n!) \approx \log \sqrt{2\pi} + \frac{1}{2}\log n + n (\log n - 1).
$$
Using this, one obtains
$$
\log A_n \approx - \log \sqrt{2\pi} -\frac{1}{2} \log n + n \log \left(\frac{30^{30}}{6^6 10^{10} 15^{15}}\right)
$$
and
$$
\log \binom{a_i n}{b_i n} \approx - \log \sqrt{2\pi} - \frac{1}{2} \log n + n \log \left(\frac{a_i^{a_i}}{b_i^{b_i}(a_i - b_i)^{a_i - b_i}}\right)
$$
Hence, if we have $A_n = \prod_{i=1}^{r} \binom{a_i n}{b_i n}$, we get
$$
- \log \sqrt{2\pi} -\frac{1}{2} \log n + n \log \left(\frac{30^{30}}{6^6 10^{10} 15^{15}}\right) \approx -r \log \sqrt{2\pi} - \frac{r}{2} \log n + n \sum_{i=1}^{r} \log \left(\frac{a_i^{a_i}}{b_i^{b_i}(a_i - b_i)^{a_i - b_i}}\right).
$$
Now, each term with same growth should match: for example, we should have
$$
\frac{30^{30}}{6^6 10^{10} 15^{15}} = \prod_{i=1}^{r} \frac{a_i^{a_i}}{b_i^{b_i}(a_i - b_i)^{a_i - b_i}}
$$
and then $-\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{r}{2} \Rightarrow r = 1$. (You can compare the "constant terms" to get the same conclusion.) This reduces to the case $r = 1$ and proving that $A_n$ cannot be written as a form of $\binom{a n}{bn}$, which should be clear.

Here's an alternative approach. Although it seems a bit excessively technical for something that appears so obvious as the first partial result. Maybe someone can come up with a better and clearer explanation.
For natural numbers $u_1\le\cdots u_p$ and $v_1\le\cdots v_q$, which we for short will just denote $u$ and $v$, we first want to prove that the function
$$
A_{u,v}(n) = A_{u_1,\ldots,u_p;v_1,\ldots,v_q}(n)
= \frac{\prod_{i=1}^p (u_in)!}{\prod_{i=1}^q (v_in)!}
$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ uniquely determines $u$ and $v$. However, that is not entirely true: only if $A_{u,v}$ is reduced in the sense that $u$ and $v$ have no common value, ie there is no $u_i=v_j$, otherwise we may eliminate those to bring $A_{u,v}$ to a reduced form.
If we have $A_{u,v}(n)$ and an alternative function $A_{u',v'}(n)$ with $u'=(u'_1,\ldots,u'_{p'})$ and $v'=(v'_1,\ldots,v'_{q'})$ where both are on reduced form, if $A_{u,v}(n)=A_{u',v'}(n)$ for all $n$, then $u'=u$ and $v'=v$.
Assume otherwise, then $A_{u,v}/A_{u',v'}=A_{U,V}$ where $U=(u,v')$, ie the concatenation of $u$ and $v'$, while $V=(u',v)$. If $A_{U,V}(n)=1$ for all $n$, we want to show that $U=V$ (meaning same values up to reordering), which would imply that $u=u'$ and $v=v'$. Let's start by reducing $(U,V)$ to $(U',V')$ by eliminating values in both $U$ and $V$. Unless the lists $U',V'$ are both empty, there must be a largest value in $U',V'$, say $w$, which occurs only in one of the lists. So, either the numerator or the denominator of $A_{U',V'}$ contains $(wn)!$.
It is known that for any $w\in\mathbb{N}$, there is an infinite number of primes on the form $wn-1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which will then be found in either the numerator or the denominator, but not both, which contradicts the assumption that $A_{U',V'}(n)=1$. So, to disallow such a $w$, both $U'$ and $V'$ must be empty.
Next, I will show that for any $A_{u,v}(n)$ on reduced form where $u,v$ are lists of length $p,q$ with $p\ge2$ and $q=p+1$, it is not possible to write $A_{u,v}(n)$ as a product of binomials $\binom{a_in}{b_in}$ for $i=1,\ldots,r$. This is basically the same idea/result as that proven by Seewoo Lee.
If we assume that they are equal, then the reduced form of $\prod_i\binom{a_in}{b_in}$, ie where we eliminate factorials that appear in both numerator and denominator, must contain the exact same factorials as $A_{u,v}$. However, if we count the number of factorials in numerator and denominator, the difference is not changed be reducing the form (since the same number of factorials are removed from numerator and denominator), and so this difference is invariant. Since each binomial has one factorial in the numerator and two in the denominator, this means that we must this difference must be $r=q-p$: $2r-r$ for the binomial expression and $q-p$ for $A_{u,v}$. But that makes $r=1$, and we need at least $r\ge p$, which is not possible.
